# Storing bags after checkout

Tags: dubai, luggage-storage

My brother and I are going to be spending a few nights in Dubai. On the night before our flight leaves, we decided not to book the room in the hostel. Is there an alternative to carrying our bags around all day?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Any hotel or hostel will allow you to check your bags at the front desk after you check out... it's commonly done, and I've never stayed anywhere that didn't allow this.

Comment: some places charge for this service while most don't

Answer (score 11):

Depending on where your hotel is located it may be more pratical to drop off your bags at the airport in the morning than leaving them in hotel. There is a left luggage facility at terminal 3 and it is easy to get to by metro.